# I need to create a gallery of images from an Array with JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a task for a homework i was give where i need to create a simple gallery  which displays 4 images.

i need to put all images into Array where each photo will be in JSON object and load the images from the array . This is where i am now:

```
<body>
 <div class="images">

</div>

(function (){
    let array_img = [
        {
            filename:"20140222_131314",
            title:"img1",        

        },
        {
            filename:"20140712_203709",
            title:"img2",

        },
        {
            filename:"20190318_182928",
            title:"img3"
        },
        {
            filename:"20190422_181219",
            title:"img4"
        }
    ]
    for (var i = 0 ; i<array_img.length ; i++){
        arr_img = array_img[i]
        var container = $(".images");
        $container.append("<img/>").attr("src=/Photos/20140222_131314.jpg")

    }

}());
```

Or should i create an additional variable img= array_img[i] and to create a text node from it and after that to append . But how to append and set the src path to all images. Maybe i need to create and empty "src" to the object sctructure?
But i am missing something . Can someone help me?

Comment: the may want to try   `$container.append("<img src=/Photos/20140222_131314.jpg/>");`

Comment: still does not work

Comment: hey , it worked i was pointing to the path incorrectly , but now it added one picture four times. Can you give me an idea how to avoid that and to add different picture to every "img" tag

Comment: Made an edit to my answer. I should get all the image filename in the array

Answer (score 1):

This should run. Make sure that you have a $ before your variables.

```js
(function() {
  let array_img = [{
      filename: "20140222_131314",
      title: "img1",

    },
    {
      filename: "20140712_203709",
      title: "img2",

    },
    {
      filename: "20190318_182928",
      title: "img3"
    },
    {
      filename: "20190422_181219",
      title: "img4"
    }
  ]
  for (var i = 0; i < array_img.length; i++) {
    $arr_img = array_img[i]
    var $container = $(".images");
    $container.append("<img src=/Photos/"+$arr_img[0]+".jpg/>");

  }

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">

</div>
```

Comment: hey , thank you for your replies. It works but it adds four "img" tags with the same picture and i want the four "img" tags to be with different pictures. Maybe i should not do it with FOR loop ?

Comment: Maybe my condition is not correct , or i should do it with Do/While , but again the condition can be tricky .

Answer (score 0):

I made it like that and now it works . I don't know if this is the best way to do it but...

```
(function (){
    let array_img = [
        {
            filename:"20140222_131314.jpg",
            title:"img1",  


        },
        {
            filename:"20140712_203709.jpg",
            title:"img2",

        },
        {
            filename:"20190318_182928.jpg",
            title:"img3"
        },
        {
            filename:"20190422_181219.jpg",
            title:"img4"
        }
    ]
    for (var i = 0 ; i<array_img.length ; i++){
        var arr_img = array_img = [i]
        var $container = $(".images");
        $container.append(arr_img[i+1],"<img src=photos/20140222_131314.jpg>")
        $container.append(arr_img[i+1],"<img src=photos/20140712_203709.jpg>")
        $container.append(arr_img[i+1],"<img src=photos/20190318_182928.jpg>")
        $container.append(arr_img[i+1],"<img src=photos/20190422_181219.jpg>")


    }

}());
```